# SOAP : NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces

Tags: java, web-services, soap

In my SOAP application i am getting this error

> NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.

while sending the request.

How to fix this issue. I tried using the

```
SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xml","http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace");
```

But it do not help me. Please tell me details.

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Don't do that - the SOAP framework will manage the infrastructural namespaces for you; you can't, and shouldn't try to, change that behaviour, or you'll get that error.

Why are you trying to do this?